# Can "copying A of B" mean "copying A from B"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

> May is the earlier verb, showing up in manuscripts from the 8th century. It originally referred to having strength or power, and then very quickly developed a meaning that referred to ability. This particular meaning is no longer in current use, but we find a late representative of this use in Chaucer’s Canterbury Tales from 1395: “We mowen nat…It ouertake, it slit awey so faste” (“We may not overtake it, it slid away so fast”). May also developed a meaning referring to possibility, which we’re still familiar with today (“I may be able to have lunch with you this Thursday”), and the meaning that schoolteachers insist it has today–one that grants permission (“You may use the bathroom”). All four of these meanings were in use before 1000AD.

> Around that time, can came on the scene. It was a verb that originally meant “to know,” and then “to know how to do something,” and then “to have the ability to do something.” This last meaning, which showed up around 1300, was can’s first semantic overlap with may. The overlap continued: by 1500, both can and may were used to refer to ability and possibility. Given that there was already some overlap between the two words, it’s not surprising that by the end of the 1800s, can also came to mean “to have permission.” (If there’s anything surprising in that, it’s perhaps that it took so long for can to copy that meaning of may’s.)

(from https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/when-to-use-can-and-may)

Here, “to copy that meaning of may’s” means “to copy the meaning of having permission from may’s one meaning of granting permission”? or “to copy that meaning of may’s” means “to copy the meaning of having permission among may’s different meanings”(that is, “that meaning of may’s” is such a phrase with double posseissive as a friend of mine)? Please answer me directly whether the former interpretation is adequate or the latter interpretation is adequate.

(I think the former interpretation is adequate, because I think "having permission" means possessing permission that has already been granted, and the meaning of having permission is not included in may’s different meanings(that is, the meaning of having strength or power, the meaning of ability, the meaning of possibility, the meaning of granting permission).)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's the _fourth_ question that has been asked in very similar words about exactly the same passage.

Comment: As a permission auxiliary, may is more formal and less common than can, which (except in fixed phrases such as if I may) can be substituted for it. However, may is particularly associated with permission given by the speaker. That is, a difference is sometimes felt between 'You may leave when you like' [='I permit you ...'] and 'You can leave when you like' [='You are permitted ...'], which can mean permission in a more general and impersonal sense.

Comment: Not all English speakers acknowledge this distinction, however; and the prescriptive bias in favour of may leads to its use in official documents and notices, etc, as in 'Visitors may reclaim necessary travel expenses up to a limit of 50 pounds', even where there is no restriction to 'speaker's permission'.

Comment: This excerpt is from Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language, by Quirk, Greenbaum, Leech, Svartvik(Lingman, 1985). I think 'I permit you to ~'='I grant permission to ~' and 'You are permitted to ~'='You have permission to ~'. That is, I think granting permission is different from having permission.

Comment: The first paragraph tells us that _may_ can have more than one meaning - possibility and permission. So it's your second interpretation that is the correct one.

Comment: Then, why is the author writing not "that meaning of may" but "that meaning of may's"? I think “that meaning of may’s” can not be interpreted as a double possessive. If the author is considering the meaning of having permission one of the meanings of may, then "that meaning of may's" doesn’t need the apostrophe or the “s” at the end of “may”. "that meaning of may's" should simply be “that meaning of may".

Comment: Could you think why I have quoted from <Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language>? I think may has the meaning of granting permission, but can has the meaning of having permission respectively. Of course, here exists some exception also. That is, may has the meaning of having permission in guides such as tax guide or regulations such as traffic rules.

Comment: I'm sure **that meaning of _may_'s** is intended as a double possessive.

Comment: There are two more exceptions I omitted. First, if the expressions of ‘I may~.’(=I have permission to~), ‘We may~.’(=We have permission to~), and ‘May you~?’(=Do you have permission to~?) are possible any, they are exceptionally possible and may in them has the meaning of having permission. Second, there are some cases where can can be interpreted as not only having the meaning of permission but also having the meaning of ability or possibility, so we have to use may instead of can for the purpose of preventing from confusion. In this cases, may has the meaning of having permission.